# How prove this limit $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n}^{9n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+1}+k}=\ln{3}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

> show  that: this limit
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n}^{9n-1}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+1}+k}=\ln{3}$$

my idea: since
$$\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+1}+k}=\sqrt{k^2+1}-k$$

then I can't.Thank you

Comment: I know this isn't English SE, but I just wanted to point out that "can't" needs to be followed by a bare infinitive (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinitive), in this case like "can't continue" / "can't see what to do next". Also, "Since X." is never a complete sentence. We can say something like "Since X, Y." / "Y, since X." to mean that "since we know X, Y follows.".

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **Observation.** If $a_{k} \sim c/k$ as $k \to \infty$, then we have
>   $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{pn < k \leq qn} a_{k} = c\log(q/p). $$

*Proof.* Given $\epsilon > 0$, choose $N$ large so that $k > pN$ then
$$ \frac{c-\epsilon}{k} \leq a_{k} \leq \frac{c+\epsilon}{k}. \tag{1} $$

Now define $H(x) = \sum_{k \leq x} \frac{1}{k}$ and recall that $H(x) = \gamma + \log x + o(1)$ as $x \to \infty$. Summing (1) over $pn < k \leq qn$ with $n \geq N$, we have

$$ (c-\epsilon)\{ H(qn) - H(pn) \} \leq \sum_{pn < k \leq qn} a_{k} \leq (c+\epsilon)\{ H(qn) - H(pn) \}. $$

Taking $n\to\infty$, it follows that

$$ (c-\epsilon) \log(q/p)
\leq \liminf_{n\to\infty} \sum_{pn < k \leq qn} a_{k}
\leq \limsup_{n\to\infty} \sum_{pn < k \leq qn} a_{k}
\leq (c+\epsilon) \log(q/p). $$

Letting $\epsilon \to 0$, the conclusion follows. ////

Now you can apply this observation to your problem.

Comment: Nice answer. +1

Answer (score 7):

Notice $\frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+1}+k}$ is monotonic decreasing, we have

$$\sum_{k=n}^{9n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+1}+k} \ge
\int_n^{9n}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x} \ge \sum_{k=n+1}^{9n}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+1}+k}\\
$$
This implies
$$\left| \sum_{k=n}^{9n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+1}+k} - 
\int_n^{9n}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x} \right|
\le \frac{1}{\sqrt{n^2+1}+n} - \frac{1}{\sqrt{(9n)^2+1}+9n} < \frac{1}{2n}
$$
and hence

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=n}^{9n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+1}+k}
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \int_n^{9n}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x}\tag{*1}$$
Notice in the indefinite integral,
$$\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x} = \int\left(\sqrt{x^2+1}-x\right) dx
= \frac12\left( x(\sqrt{x^2+1} -x) + \log(\sqrt{x^2+1}+x) \right)
= \frac12\left[ \color{blue}{\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+1}+x} + \log(\sqrt{1+x^{-2}}+1)} + \log x\right]
$$
The first two term (in blue) converges to a constant $\frac12 + \log 2$ as $x\to\infty$.
they won't contribute to the limit in RHS of $(*1)$. As a result,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=n}^{9n-1}\frac{1}{\sqrt{k^2+1}+k}
= \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac12\left(\log(9n)-\log(n)\right) = \log 3.$$

Comment: The steps where one evaluates the integral can be shortened somewhat since $2x\leqslant\sqrt{x^2+1}+x\leqslant(2+1/n)x$ for every $x\geqslant n$. (And this observation, used on the sums themselves, also allows to bypass completely the comparison with integrals if one knows that the $n$th harmonic number is $\sim\log n$...)

Comment: @Did, it is true this can be shortened. However, my main purpose is to demonstrate one can evaluate the limit of the sum by evaluating the limit of corresponding integral.

Answer (score 4):

By multiplying and dividing the sum by *n*, we notice that this is nothing else but the [Riemann sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sum) for $~\displaystyle\int_1^9\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^2}+x}=\int_1^9\frac{dx}{2x}=\bigg[\frac{\ln x}2\bigg]_1^9=\ln3$.

Comment: Actually these are NOT the Riemann sums for $x\mapsto1/(2x)$ hence the argument, as it is given, is at best a heuristics.

Comment: @Did: It can be made rigorous with a bit of [squeezing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

Comment: I know. But "this is nothing else but the Riemann sum for..." is simply not true.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a_n$ denote the $n$-th term. Then this limit follows from the inequalities

$$
\int_n^{9n}\frac{dx}{2x+1}\leq\sum_{k=n}^{9n-1}\frac{1}{2k+1}\leq a_n \leq\sum_{k=n}^{9n-1}\frac{1}{2k}\leq\int_{n-1}^{9n-1}\frac{dx}{2x}.
$$

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n}^{9n - 1}{1 \over \root{k^{2} + 1} + k}
     =\ln\pars{3}:\ {\large ?}}$

> \begin{align}
> \mbox{With}\quad S_{N} \equiv \sum_{k = 1}^{N}{1 \over \root{k^{2} + 1} + k}\,,
> \qquad
> \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n}^{9n - 1}{1 \over \root{k^{2} + 1} + k}=
> \lim_{n \to \infty}\pars{S_{9n - 1} - S_{n - 1}}
> \end{align}

\begin{align}
S_{N}&=\sum_{k = 1}^{N}\pars{{1 \over \root{k^{2} + 1} + k} - {1 \over 2k}}
+\half\,H_{N}
\\[3mm]& H_{N}:\mbox{Harmonic Number} = \Psi\pars{N + 1} + \gamma
\end{align}
$\ds{\Psi\pars{z}\mbox{: Digamma Function.}\quad
     \gamma\mbox{: Euler-Mascheroni Constant}}$.

> $\ds{\Psi\pars{z} \sim\ln\pars{z}\ \mbox{when}\ \verts{z} \gg 1}$ and
>   $\ds{\pars{S_{N} - \half\,H_{N}}}$ converges in the limit $\ds{N \to \infty}$.
>   Then,
>   \begin{align}&\color{#66f}{\large%
> \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=n}^{9n - 1}{1 \over \root{k^{2} + 1} + k}}
> =\half\,\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{\Psi\pars{9n} - \Psi\pars{n}}
> =\half\,\lim_{n \to \infty}\bracks{\ln\pars{9n} - \ln\pars{n}}
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#66f}{\large\ln\pars{3}}
> \end{align}